# How to achieve smooth drawing with C# (like Paint .NET)?

Tags: c#, drawing, mousemove

How Paint .NET can draw so fast using C#? Sample: The ellipse perimeter is drawn while the mouse is being dragged without any visible delay. At a simple windows form application in C# If you use the MouseMove event of a Picturebox and draw an ellipse based on the mouse position, there will be a lot of delay and flickering! So, how they do it so smoothly?

Comment: Great question - probably doesn't belong on S.O., but still a great question.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/directx/archive/2009/08/14/paint-net-uses-directwrite.aspx

Comment: Here is the link to an answer that has tips from the author of Paint.NET https://stackoverflow.com/a/11025428/11425141

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They probably use WPF. It is much much faster than forms.

Answer (score 4):

I have no special knowledge of the Paint.Net code, but most likely it's using [Double Buffering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3t7htc9c.aspx), and probably implemented by hand on a custom drawing surface rather than the simplistic implementation in the pre-packaged controls.

Comment: Thanks. I will search for some DB sample to see if it really improves the drawing.

Answer (score 4):

Paint.NET calls Update() after calling Invalidate() which forces an immediate, synchronous WM_PAINT.

Comment: To elaborate on the lower-level details: `Invalidate()` in WinForms calls into the native `InvalidateRect()` function. `Update()` calls the native `UpdateWindow()`. `Refresh()` is the same as calling `Invalidate(true)` followed by `Update()`.

Answer (score 2):

To get smooth drawing you should:

- Use Double Buffering (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b367a457.aspx)
- Use a dedicated toolkit for rendering (OpenGL/DirectDraw etc)

The best way to go in this case is with Double Buffering - it's supported 'out of the box' in the .NET framework, requires very little work, and will eliminate flickering.

Comment: I think double buffering wont fix the delay problem that is more cleary noted when the mouse is moved faster and a gap start to appear betwen its position and the ellipse being drawn.